# MySQL UPDATE Math Not Working?

Tags: mysql, math

I am performing a query that will subtract a balance from a row by 1. However, after the query will run successfully once, the math becomes off.

If I subtract 0.1 from 1.0, it gives me 0.9. However, the next time I subtract 0.1, I get 0.8000000000000001. Here is the query I'm using:

```
UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET BALANCE=BALANCE-$amt WHERE ID=$user_id
```

$amt is 0.1 and $user_id is 1, in this case.

Why does the math change after a successful query? Thanks!

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Don't store your balance as `float`, try storing it as `decimal (10,2)`

Comment: @TinTran I changed BALANCE to decimal, but it won't even do any math. It stays the same. I don't know what the (10,2) thing is though.

Comment: (10,2) means there are total 10 numbers you can at max enter and in which 2 will be decimal places...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @tintran I figured out that it had to do with the LENGTH/VALUE part of being a decimal. I changed it to (10,8). 8 is because I am dealing in Bitcoin and 8 decimal places is the max I could go.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE ACCOUNTS SET BALANCE=ROUND((BALANCE-$amt),2) WHERE ID=$user_id
```

try this....